# Proxy does not work, when I set it programmaticaly in Java using Jaunt library

Tags: java, web-scraping, proxy, jvm, jaunt-api

I have simple scraping program based on Joint library, that needs to set and change proxy programmaticaly.

```
private static void setProxy(){
        System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", ProxyProducer.getProxy()); // this class just returns host address from list
        System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", ProxyProducer.PORT);
        ProxyAuthenticator.setCredentials(ProxyProducer.LOGIN, ProxyProducer.PASSWORD); //Joint's authentificator-wrapper
    }
```

But it does not work. No errors, no proxy-applying, response is ok but no proxy.
Could this be because of Windows? I have 10 and at startup there are no requests for permissions, in contrast to many programs is very strange.

Comment: What is the example URL that you are trying to access? What is the protocol of said URL, is it HTTPS?

Comment: Yes, it is. Url is standart, no parameters or else, based on  https:// prefix